# Display Images Over List Item Menu Links

Tags: html, css

I need a cross-browser solution for having list item menu links with images. I'm using the default ASP.NET MVC 4 template and I have the following generated HTML:

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/Home/Item01">
      <img src='/Images/MenuItem01.gif'/>
      Menu Item 01
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/Home/Item02">
      <img src='/Images/MenuItem02.gif'/>
      Menu Item 02
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/Home/Item03">
      <img src='/Images/MenuItem03.gif'/>
      Menu Item 03
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

The CSS:

```css
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EY3ad/

I'd like to have each image above the text and centralized. I haven't done pure HTML and CSS in years so any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: if image would be above the text, text will hide obviously do you want to make it like that...

Comment: No, I'd like the image to be above the text. Both the image and text should be seen as a combined image link

Comment: So like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/EY3ad/1/ …?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706477/center-image-above-list-items

Comment: @CBroe yes except in IE10 there is a border around the image. Setting `border: none;` doesn't seem to work. FYI this also needs to work for IE9 and IE8.

Comment: `border:none` for the `img` element takes the border away in IE 10: http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/EY3ad/5/ Can’t test in IE < 9, because jsfiddle doesn’t work too well in those modes – but I think it should work in those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EY3ad/2/)?

The HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="/Home/Item01">
          <img src='http://lorempixel.com/48/48'/>
        <span>Menu Item 01</span>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/Home/Item02">
          <img src='http://lorempixel.com/48/48'/>
          <span>Menu Item 02</span>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/Home/Item03">
          <img src='http://lorempixel.com/48/48'/>
          <span>Menu Item 03</span>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:relative;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a img { display:block; margin:auto; } 
ul#menu li a span{position:absolute; top:0; text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Also, you need to either reduce the size of your font or increase the size of the image make both things look like a part of the same image. @Sameer Singh

Comment: Might be a silly question but why would I need a rule for `span` in the list item menu? There isn't any in the HTML.

Comment: I have included a span in your HTML. You need to have a span. Your HTML has a text after the <img> tag which doesnt give any characteristic to it, so if you want any kind of alterations as to make text above image i.e the one that you want in this scenario, text should be marked up inside a tag and that is the reason I have injected a span inside your html. Hope the reason is justified. - @SameerSingh

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the solution - @SameerSingh

Comment: Fair point, I hadn't thought of that. I've tried your solution, but the text is wrapped so I changed the CSS from `ul#menu li a span{position:absolute; top:0; text-align:center;}` to `ul#menu li a span{position:relative; top:0; text-align:center;}` Thanks for your help, I need to check a few more things in my local project before accepting an answer.

Comment: No Problem, but nesting position relative inside a position relative is not a good way. - @SameerSingh

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`ul.menu li{
    background: url(images/<image-name>.gif) no-repeat;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:4%;
    margin-top:1%;
}`

Comment: I'd prefer not to place the image path in CSS - I need to dynamically set it so I am using ASP.NET's Razor syntax (`@Url.Content()`)